# Are there other products than Adobe's that support ClearScan or similiar?

Tags: windows, linux, pdf, ocr

Starting with Acrobat 9, Adobe engineers added a new flavor of OCR called ClearScan.

[The advantages of the ClearScan over Searchable Image OCR](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/better-pdf-ocr-clearscan-smaller-looks-better) are both  in size and clarity. 
The biggest innovation of Clearscan is that:

> ClearScan does not replace the font with your system fonts. Rather, a
>   custom font it is created to match the visual appearance of the
>   pixels.<sup>[1](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/better-pdf-ocr-clearscan-smaller-looks-better)</sup>

Are there other products than Adobe's that support Clearscan or similar products that use a custom font that is created to match the visual appearance of the pixels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > [Smoothscan](https://github.com/ncraun/smoothscan/) is a tool to convert scanned text into a vectorized
   >   output form. Because printed text is assembled from fonts, each
   >   particular letter (like ‘o’) will have the same shape as every other
   >   ‘o’ in the document. We can take advantage of this, by building a
   >   table of such symbols, and represent each occurrence of a symbol with
   >   a reference to that symbol’s table entry. This will save a lot of
   >   space, and a similar idea is used in djvu’s jb2 mode and JBIG2 for
   >   PDF.
   >
   > smoothscan builds up this table, but instead of filling the table with
   >   the original raster images, it vectorizes each symbol. Vector images
   >   will look smoother than their raster equivalents, and can be scaled
   >   without introducing pixelation. These properties result in a smaller
   >   output file size, as well as making the scanned text images more
   >   readable.
   >
   > smoothscan saves the vectorized images into a custom TrueType font and
   >   embeds the font into the output pdf file. Currently each symbol is
   >   mapped to an arbitrary letter in the font, but in future versions you
   >   could run OCR on each symbol, and ensure that the ‘o’ image is
   >   associate with the ‘o’ character encoding in the generated font.

   [A search of pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/search/?query=smoothscan&type=smart) returns no *smoothscan* package for any
   *Linux* distro.  So it needs to be compiled from the source code, its *README* notes these dependencies:

   - [leptonica](http://leptonica.com/)
   - [libharu](http://libharu.org/)
   - [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/)
   - [fontforge](http://fontforge.org/) (compiled w/ python support):
   - [python](http://www.python.org/)

   On a *Ubuntu* box, most of these can be had like so:

   ```
   apt install libleptonica-dev libhpdf-dev potrace python-fontforge
   ```

   A test with a sample picture.  Load the *README* in `abiword`, print
   it to a *.ps* file, and then...

   - Use *ghostscript* to convert that *.ps* file to *.tif*,
   - *convert* that to monochrome **.tif**, (the *only* input `smoothscan` accepts)
   - run `smoothscan`
   - compare the various file sizes with `wc -c`:

     ```
     gs -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -o README.tif README.ps
     convert -monochrome README.tif README.mono.tif
     smoothscan -o README.pdf README.mono.tif
     wc -c README README.ps README.*tif README.pdf | head -n -1
     ```

   Output:

   ```
     2432 README
    83516 README.ps
    33707 README.tif
    33618 README.mono.tif
    20394 README.pdf
   ```

   First paragraph of resulting *README.pdf*, showing vectorized fonts:

   [image: image of first smoothscan paragraph, showing vectorized fonts.]
2. The *[djvu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DjVu)* file format
   includes a *[JB2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DjVu#Compression)*
   option, which is much the same thing as *ClearScan*.

   Using the above *README.ps* input, the `any2djvu` util returns
   excellent results with:

   ```
   any2djvu README.ps
   ```

   ...the resulting *README.djvu* is only 7K, (1/3 the size of
   `smoothscan`'s output), and looks sharper:

   [image: any2djvu image of first two lines of README.djvu]

   That sharpness is probably helped by not using a monochrome *.tiff*
   as input.  That test is an unfair comparison.  Let's try it *with*
   the mono rasterized *.tiff*:

   ```
   # "-f 6" sets input format to "Scanned Document - B&W - >400 dpi"
   any2djvu -f 6 README.mono.tif
   ```

   Now the output is less than 6k, but looks a bit jaggier:

   [image]

   Unlike `smoothscan`'s *.pdf* output, the *.djvu* output allows text
   selection, even with rasterized input.

   One bad thing however, [`any2djvu`](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/) needs [an online
   server](http://any2djvu.djvuzone.org) to do the conversion work -- it's not a suitable tool
   for confidential documents.

Comment: Thanks for the nice post, I thought that there were no alternatives but it seems there are rather good ones +1/accepted

Comment: Very nice answer, but... Did you say you converted the PS file to DJVU? Wasn't the Postscript file already vectorized and with selectable text?

Comment: Whether the _.ps_ file was vectorized or rasterized, I dunno, it's whatever _abiword_ prints out to (since the _.ps_ file is 85K, which is even bigger than the _.tif_, I'd guess it's rasterized).  I'm unhappy with the present PS>DJVU  _any2djvu_ test  though, and am still looking for ways to test _djvu_ against rasterized text.

Comment: Is smoothscan still supported? The latest commit on the git is dated in 2013, 5 years ago

Comment: In hindsight, using sample text that included the name of the first program makes the `djvu` entry more confusing...

Comment: Could DjVu format be used offline with the `cjb2` command (`apt install djvulibre-bin`? And am I right in thinking that the DjVu option means your documents aren't in PDF format and therefore aren't natively readable on most platforms? And no vector font is created as in ClearScan or smoothscan, it's just a compressed raster image?

Comment: To answer my own question, and explain why `any2djvu` does not work offline: "Although it is conceivable that adequate open source replacements for [LizardTech's high performance DjVu encoders] will eventually become available, [they] are not included in DjVuLibre. This means that, at the moment, certain types of document compressed with LizardTech's commercial compressors or with the on-line conversion services (such as Any2DjVu) will end up smaller (and in some cases higher-quality) than the ones compressed with the DjVuLibre encoders."

Answer (score 3):

**NEW ANSWER**

My [PDFsak](https://github.com/raffaem/pdftools) can now simulate Adobe Clearscan (using potrace).

**OLD ANSWER**

Having [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/), [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) and [pdftools](https://github.com/raffaem/pdftools) (disclaimer: I am the author of pdftools). Assuming you have an input PDF file called `input.pdf`:

1. Convert every page in a BMP file using ImageMagick:

```
mkdir bmp
magick convert -density 300 input.pdf -quality 100 ./bmp/input.bmp
```

2. (optional) pre-process image files:

```
mkdir bmpproc
for /r %%i in (./bmp/*.bmp) do mkbitmap ./bmp/%%~ni.bmp --output ./bmpproc/%%~ni.pbm
```

3. Rasterize every BMP images and save the output in a PDF:

```
mkdir pdf
for /r %%i in (./bmpproc/*.pbm) do potrace ./bmpproc/%%~ni.pbm -b pdf --output ./pdf/%%~ni.pdf
```

4. Merge the output PDF files together:

`pdftools --input-dir .\pdf --output merged.pdf --fitpaper`

**EDIT:** You can obtain a version of your PDF vectorized and OCRed. Thus the only difference with Adobe ClearScan is that the fonts are not embedded (but the text is saved as a "Path" object nevertheless

1. Using ImageMagick, convert your pdf to bmp images (one per page)

`magick convert -monochrome -density 300 -alpha off input.pdf ./bmp/input.bmp`

2. Using potrace, postprocess your bmp, save to pbm files, and generate a vectorized version of your pdf

```
for /r %%i in (./bmp/*.bmp) do mkbitmap ./bmp/%%~ni.bmp --output ./bmpproc/%%~ni.pbm
for /r %%i in (./bmpproc/*.pbm) do potrace ./bmpproc/%%~ni.pbm -b pdf --output ./vectorized/%%~ni.pdf
```

3. Using TesserAct, OCR your pdf file

`for /r %%i in (./bmpproc/*.pbm) do tesseract ./bmpproc/%%~ni.pbm ./ocred/%%~ni pdf`

4. Using pdftools, merge together the pages of the single files for the ocr-ed and the vectorized version:

```
python -m pdftools --input-dir ocred  --overwrite --fitpaper --output ocred.pdf --natural-sort
python -m pdftools --input-dir vectorized  --overwrite --fitpaper --output vectorized.pdf --natural-sort
```

5. Now we need to remove the image layer from the ocr-ed file (because we will use the vectorized image). Using qPDF, generate an uncompressed version of your ocr-ed file:

`qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable ocr.pdf ocr-uncompressed.pdf`

6. Remove whatever is not an image from your ocr-uncompressed.pdf file with the following python 3 script

```
with open("ocr-uncompressed.pdf", "rb") as fileh:
    filedata = fileh.read()
    
streams = filedata.split("endstream".encode("utf8"))
outdata = bytearray()

for rawstream in streams[:-1]:
    before, stream = rawstream.split("stream".encode("utf8"))
    outdata += before + "stream".encode("utf8") 
    if not stream.startswith(bytearray.fromhex("0aff")):
        outdata += stream         
    outdata += "endstream".encode("utf8")
    
outdata += streams[-1]        
        
with open("ocr-no-img.pdf", "wb") as fileh:
    fileh.write(outdata)
```

7. Now using pdftk, overlay the ocr-ed version (with no images) to the vectorized version:

`pdftk vectorized.pdf multibackground ocr-no-image.pdf output mergedlayer.pdf`

and you are done!